# How to install HDF5 version 1.8 on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: lua

I am working on torch but when I try to run the following command:

```
require 'hdf5'
```

this returns the following error:

```
/home/mobeen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/hdf5/ffi.lua:71: Unsupported HDF5 version: 1.10.0
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /home/mobeen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/hdf5/ffi.lua:71: in function 'checkHDF5Version'
    /home/mobeen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/hdf5/ffi.lua:78: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    /home/mobeen/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:54: in function 'include'
    /home/mobeen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/hdf5/init.lua:29: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406500
th> ^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 luajit
```